# Passing variable to jQuery plugin parameter

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I've got a problem figuring out how to pass a variable to parameter of the `ajaxForm()` function. I am getting templatedir path from hidden form field after clicking on form button in jQuery (this works great) and I can pass it to other function but not to the `ajaxForm()` parameter:

```
    var templatedir;

    // Get variable of templatedir
    $('form#contact input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(){
        templatedir = $('input[name=templatedir]').fieldValue();   
    });

    // Validate Form
    function validateform(formData, jqForm, options) {         
        ...
        // IF I CALL TEMPLATEDIR HERE IT WORKS
    }   

    // Send to PHPMailer
    $("form#contact").ajaxForm({
        url: templatedir, // IT DOESNT WORK HERE
        type: 'post', 
        beforeSubmit: validateform,
        target: '#msg',
        clearForm: true
    });
```

I tried the solution from this answer ([How do i pass variables between functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600508/how-do-i-pass-variables-between-functions-in-javascript)) as you can see but it doesn't work.

Comment: Mmm...is this right? `templatedir = $('input[name=templatedir]').fieldValue();`

Comment: Yes, this is right, I can pass result to console.log and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `templatedir` is undefined.

You should call `ajaxForm()` in click event.

```
$('form#contact input[type="submit"]').on('click',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Send to PHPMailer
    $("form#contact").ajaxForm({
        url: $('input[name=templatedir]').fieldValue(),
        type: 'post', 
        beforeSubmit: validateform,
        target: '#msg',
        clearForm: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The points of interest are:

- you cannot use the templatedir variable before you set it
- change `templatedir = $('input[name=templatedir]').fieldValue();`  to

  templatedir = $('input[name=templatedir]').val();
- remove `url: templatedir, // IT DOESNT WORK HERE` and set it in validateform: before form submission

My snippet:

```js
var templatedir;

$(function () {
  $('form#contact input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
    templatedir = $('input[name=templatedir]').val();
  });
  function validateform(formData, jqForm, options) {
    // because you now are in the beforesubmit event
    // you can change the url.....
    options.url = templatedir;
  }

  $("form#contact").ajaxForm({
    type: 'post',
    beforeSubmit: validateform,
    target: '#msg',
    clearForm: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>

<form id="contact" action="www.google.com" method="post">
    templatedir: <input type="text" name="templatedir"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
</form>
<div id="msg"></div>
```